# Embedded Table View in UIView container

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, user-interface, uitableview

So here's the case:

[image]

I wish to fill the prototype cells with the names of the friends selected in the UIPickerView over there. I have programatically filled the picker with the correct data, and set its properties using the delegate functions.

The "New Game Friends View" you see here has its own viewcontroller subclass, as has the table view, which I attempt to embed into a UIView on the "New Game Friends View".

I have in many ways tried to add data to the prototype cells, but with no luck. Here's my current addBtnClicked function:

```
- (IBAction)addBtnClicked:(id)sender {
    WHGFriendTableViewController* tabView = (WHGFriendTableViewController*) [[self childViewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];

    NSInteger row = [friendPicker selectedRowInComponent:0];
    [[tabView selectedFriends] addObject:[[self friendList] objectAtIndex:row]];
}
```

This pretty much crashes my app. Whenever I hit the Add Friend button, the iPhone sends an abort signal, and gives back this message:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController
>   selectedFriends]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x978d530'

Any help with this problem is very appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does your tabView instance have a method/property called selectedFriends?

Comment: @rocky No, that's the NSMutableArray containing the Player objects I select from the list. When a friend is selected, this function is supposed to put it in that list, but it appears as if the app doesn't recognize childViewControllers's objectAtIndex:0 as a WHGFriendTableViewController -- which is the controller class for the TableView.

Comment: Yes I know it is some sort of NSMutableArray. My question is, is that NSMutableArray a property? The error says UIViewController received an unrecognized selector: 'selectedFriends'. Make sure you can access that property.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't because it isn't ?

Comment: Oh sorry, yes, that's a (strong, nonatomic) property of the WHGFriendTableViewController, which I synthesize in the implementation.

Comment: Oh my, I'm so clumsy! I forgot to set the subview there as an instance of my custom class. When I asked the question, it was simply implementing UITableView -.-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a property called `selectedFriends` on your New Friends view controller?
If the answer is yes try:

```
- (IBAction)addBtnClicked:(id)sender {
    WHGFriendTableViewController* tabView = (WHGFriendTableViewController*) [[self childViewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];

    NSInteger row = [friendPicker selectedRowInComponent:0];
    [[self selectedFriends] addObject:[[self friendList] objectAtIndex:row]];
}
```

If selectedFriends is a property of WHGFriendTableViewController, you should create a public method that adds a friend to the Mutable Array and call it from addBtnClicked IBAction.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this. Are there any other "pitfalls" I might have stepped on? Forgotten to initialize something, or include delegates needed for the container? The container is an instance of UIView, this is correct, right?

Comment: Oh my, I'm so clumsy! I forgot to set the subview there as an instance of my custom class. When I asked the question, it was simply implementing UITableView -.-

Comment: Hmm... I would set the custom table view as a property too and access through self.tabView. I say this because I'm not sure childViewControllers will return always the table view for index 0